# opening dialog box in front of user who is on my website via IP address

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have my website www.bccfalna.com where I sell EBooks. I use Histats for getting **Live Information** of my Visitor. So, When someone visits my site, I get various kinds of Live Information of my Visitor like Operating System, User Agent (Web Browser), **IP Address**, etc... of my Visitor via Histats Admin Panel.

Since, I have seen in any Commercial CHAT Program, that we can Open a CHAT Box in front of our Visitor via our Admin Panel. I just want to create this type of Functioanlity. I mean, **when someone visits my Site, I want to open a CHAT Dialog Box in front of my Visitor via my own Admin Panel.**

I know my each user's IP Address, so I can identify my each visitor uniqually, but how I open a jQuery Dialog Box in front of my Visitor when I want?

My Question is, How I can do it with what technologies while my site is created in WordPress CMS?

Comment: This may help: http://analytics.blogspot.in/2013/08/google-analytics-launches-real-time-api.html

Comment: No, it is not helping. I am using WordPress and I want to create a Plugin, from where I want to be in touch of my Visitor. I want to monitor my each Visitor about who have visited how many pages and what is his/her favoriate topic on my site. So that, I can make any specific type of offer in front of him with displaying a Dialog Box or CHAT Box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zopim](http://zopim.com/) for that.

It can track any visitor, see from what page they went to which and give you the chat functionality, which you can press at any time to interact with user.

its free for one operator so i think you can use it for you without any costs.

Comment: Ya, I want same functionality like ZOPIM to interact with my User but I want to create that functionality myself because ZOPIM is restricted very much. I want to logic working behind this Functionality, so that I can code it as a WordPress Plugin.

Comment: You can have something like [quick chat](http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-chat/) or [support live chat](http://wordpress.org/plugins/conversion-support-live-chat/) but if you wish to code it yourself, you just need to understand a little about websockets in php, maybe [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) will help

Answer (score 0):

Now I am using a WP-CHAT Plugin available at https://www.mylivechat.com/default.aspx

This Plugin is sufficient for me because the Free Version gives us 100 CHAT per day, Plus I can popup a CHAT Window in front of my Visitor at Live Time selectively, what was my requirement in this Question.